# Tkinter changing variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In this program, I tried to create a loop that would increase the value of the variable `X` during each iteration

```
from tkinter import *

def func(x=0):
    x +=1
    root.after(10, func, x)
    print(x)
           
root = Tk()
btn1 = Button(root, text="click", command=func)
btn1.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

When I press the button for the first time everything works correctly.
But when I press the button again, I see something like this:

```
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    1
    8
    2
    9
    3 
    10
    4 
    11
    5 
    12
    6 
    13
    7 
    14
    8
    15
```

It looks like the old and new values of the variable are mixed.
I think I should remove the first `func()`run from `mainloop()` to do list.
But how?

Comment: Use a global variable

Comment: With pressing button twice, you are calling `root.after()` twice. Scheduling two events to take place. Do you want the loop to cancel when you start a new loop, or do you want to restart the loop or do you want ignore the button press

Comment: @CoolCloud I want to cancel previous loop when i starting new

Comment: That means you want to reset the value of `x` that is fairly simple.

Comment: @CoolCloud yes, I found a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cancel the first loop, before starting a new loop:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Counter:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.x = 0
        self.root = root
        self.id = None

    def restart(self):
        if self.id is not None:
            self.root.after_cancel(self.id)
        self.x = 0
        self.next()

    def next(self):
        self.x += 1
        print(self.x)
        self.id = self.root.after(10, self.next)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    counter = Counter(root)
    tk.Button(root, text="click", command=counter.restart).pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *

x = 0

def func():
    global x
    x += 1
    print(x)

root = Tk()
btn1 = Button(root, text="click", command=func)
btn1.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

or if you want to destroy it in 10 milliseconds:

```
from tkinter import *

x = 0

def func():
    global x
    x += 1
    print(x)
    root.after(10, root.destroy)

root = Tk()
btn1 = Button(root, text="click", command=func)
btn1.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

or to continously increase x

```
from tkinter import *

x = 0

def func():
    global x
    x += 1
    print(x)
    root.after(10, func)

root = Tk()
btn1 = Button(root, text="click", command=func)
btn1.grid()
root.mainloop()
```